# How to find all views that have "broken or missing handler"?

Tags: 7, views

Is there an easy way to get a list of all views that have a "broken or missing handler" ? To make sure it is ok to disable a module that defines views plugins.

I think in D8 we have proper dependency management for this stuff. But in D7?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a debug option within Views's advanced settings that will print out debug statements via the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) when a handler is broken.

Combined with Devel's **Execute PHP** block/form, you can use the execute the following snippet to enable debugging, evoke execution on all Views, and review the output messages for any broken handler warnings between each execution prompt.

```
// Capture/set debug settings.
$views_debug = variable_get('views_devel_output', FALSE);
$views_region = variable_get('views_devel_region', 'watchdog');
variable_set('views_devel_output', TRUE);
variable_set('views_devel_region', 'message');

// Execute all views/displays
foreach( views_get_all_views() as $view) { 
  $displays = array_keys($view->display);
  foreach($displays as $display) {
     dpm("Executing $view->name ($display):");
     $view->execute($display);
     $view = $view->clone_view();
  }
}

// Reset debug settings.
variable_set('views_devel_output', $views_debug);
variable_set('views_devel_region', $views_region);
```

Comment: Don't we need to explore all the displays of each view?

Comment: Thats a good point, I've adjusted the code to handle multiple display execution.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to do similar in D9 recently (after some core and module updates). Here's the code that I used:

```
use Drupal\views\Views;

// Capture/set debug settings.
$views_debug = \Drupal::state()->get('views_devel_output', FALSE);
$views_region = \Drupal::state()->get('views_devel_region', 'watchdog');
\Drupal::state()->set('views_devel_output', TRUE);
\Drupal::state()->set('views_devel_region', 'message');

// Execute all views/displays
$views = Views::getAllViews();
foreach( $views as $view) {
  dpm("Running view id ".$view->get('id')."...");
  $displays = $view->get('display');
  $view = Views::getView($view->get('id'));
  foreach($displays as $display) {
    dpm("Executing $view->name (".$display['id']."):");
    $view->setDisplay($display);
    $view->preExecute();
    $view->execute();
    $content = $view->buildRenderable($display);
  }
}

// Reset debug settings.
\Drupal::state()->set('views_devel_output', $views_debug);
\Drupal::state()->set('views_devel_region', $views_region);
```